# MYSQL query returns my date fields as unixtimestamps.

Tags: mysql

SIm new to coding but i have a MYSQL query that returns the required information except it returns my date fields (d.timestart and d.timefinish) as unixtimestamps.
I know i need to possibly use From Unixtime () but i dont know how to insert it.

Here is my code which works fine :)

```
SELECT g.quiz       AS'Quiz Number', 
       g.userid     AS'User Number', 
       g.grade      AS'Grade Percentage Achieved', 
       u.firstname  AS' First Name', 
       u.lastname   AS'Last Name', 
       c.name       AS'Assessment Name', 
       d.attempt    AS'Number of Attempts', 
       d.state      AS'Assessment Progress', 
       d.timestart  AS'Assessment Started', 
       d.timefinish AS'Assessment Finished' 
FROM   mdl_quiz_grades g 
       JOIN mdl_user u 
         ON u.id = g.userid 
       JOIN mdl_quiz c 
         ON c.id = g.quiz 
       JOIN mdl_quiz_attempts d 
         ON d.id = g.userid
```

Thanks Gary

Answer (score 2):

You would use `FROM_UNIXTIME`:

```
SELECT g.quiz                      AS'Quiz Number', 
       g.userid                    AS'User Number', 
       g.grade                     AS'Grade Percentage Achieved', 
       u.firstname                 AS' First Name', 
       u.lastname                  AS'Last Name', 
       c.name                      AS'Assessment Name', 
       d.attempt                   AS'Number of Attempts', 
       d.state                     AS'Assessment Progress', 
       From_unixtime(d.timestart)  AS'Assessment Started', 
       From_unixtime(d.timefinish) AS'Assessment Finished' 
FROM   mdl_quiz_grades g 
       JOIN mdl_user u 
         ON u.id = g.userid 
       JOIN mdl_quiz c 
         ON c.id = g.quiz 
       JOIN mdl_quiz_attempts d 
         ON d.id = g.userid
```

If you wanted to format that date, you would use `DATE_FORMAT` and specifiers to format it from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(d.timestart), '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS ...
```

Comment: Works great :) but where do i put the DATE_Format statement?

Comment: @GazYeah You wrap it around `FROM_UNIXTIME` like above.

Comment: Got it :)Thank you for you really prompt help.

Comment: i can see how it works now :) better to see it at work than to try read from pages of instruction :)

Comment: I tried the DATE_FORMAT function but i get NULL returns after using the MYSQL ref

Comment: @GazYeah Can I see the part where you're using `DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: Here is Code  line   DATE_FORMAT('%b %d %Y %h:%i %p', FROM_UNIXTIME(d.timestart)) AS'Assessment Started',

Comment: i put that line in place of FROM UNIXTIME statement apologies can repaste code :(

Comment: Again Thank you :) i think i just learned more in an hour than i have allday reading about it again thank you

Answer (score 1):

for formatting a unix timestamp you can try

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM myTable;
```

where the second part is a format string.

for formatting any kinds of dates and times, you can try the `DATE_FORMAT` function, eg

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM myTable;`

anyway take a look at 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

and
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: This won't work as the column is a Unix timestamp. It needs to first be converted using `FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP`. Feel free to fix your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

```
SELECT g.quiz       AS'Quiz Number', 
       g.userid     AS'User Number', 
       g.grade      AS'Grade Percentage Achieved', 
       u.firstname  AS' First Name', 
       u.lastname   AS'Last Name', 
       c.name       AS'Assessment Name', 
       d.attempt    AS'Number of Attempts', 
       d.state      AS'Assessment Progress', 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(d.timestart)  AS'Assessment Started', 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(d.timefinish) AS'Assessment Finished' 
FROM   mdl_quiz_grades g 
       JOIN mdl_user u 
         ON u.id = g.userid 
       JOIN mdl_quiz c 
         ON c.id = g.quiz 
       JOIN mdl_quiz_attempts d 
         ON d.id = g.userid
```

Comment: How do i use DATE FORMAT in script ?